# No se extrae valor de text jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un input text el cual cargo mediante ajax cuando selecciono algun valor
del select.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego intento recuperar el valor del text  para luego realizar otro paso, pero no logro recuperar el valor.

He aqui el codigo, espero me puedan colaborar.

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <text name="idControlL" id="idControlL" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
        </text>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Acciones</label>
        <select name="productos" id="productos" class="form-control" style="width:350px">
                 <option value="">Seleccione Accion</option>
        </select>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('idRiesgo',$idRiesgo,null,['class'=>'form-control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::hidden('idOpcionTratamiento',$idOpcionTratamiento,null,['class'=>'form-control','required','style' => 'width:350px']) !!}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::submit('Registrar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}

      </div>


{!! Form::close() !!}

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
  <script>

  $(document).on('change','#idControl',function(){
         var valor = $(this).val();
         sacarid(valor);
         var control =  $('idControlL').val();//---------ACA ES DONDE INTENTO RECUPERAR EL VALOR--------------------------------------
         console.log(control);
     //    acciones(control);

  });

  function sacarid(valor){

    var id = valor;

    $.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url:'{{url('sacarid')}}'+'/'+id,
      beforeSend: function () {

            },
      success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var controlL = ' ';
        for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
          controlL+= data[i].idControlL;
      $("#idControlL").html(controlL);
      //   console.log(controlL);
       // acciones(controlL);
      }
    });

 };
```

Comment: quizá intenta acceder al elemento por id, faltaría el `#` ya que el elemento con nombre `idControlL` no existe.  `$('#idControlL').val();`

Comment: Ya lo intente y igualmente no lo recupera, en consola muestra vacio.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi, gracias igualmente.